# What is $\mathbb D$

Tags: notation

What exactly is $\mathbb D$? Is it the unit ball? I think it is a subset of the reals...

Comment: A bit of context would be helpful. Where did you meet this notation?

Comment: As with any notation, it means whatever the author has defined it to mean and can mean different things in different contexts.  To know exactly what is meant, read the paragraphs leading up to where you first see the symbol used, the beginning of the book, or the end of the book where lists of symbols used are often introduced.

Comment: $\mathbb{D}_n$ can mean the n-th [dihedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some contexts (in particular complex analysis), $\mathbb D$ is a disk, or more particularly the open unit disk.

Comment: is it a 3D disk? or 2D

Comment: A disk in the complex plane.

Comment: what about $\mathbb D^3$? what does this mean?

Comment: Cartesian product of three copies of $\mathbb D$, i.e. the set of triples $(a,b,c)$ with $a,b,c \in \mathbb D$, with the product topology.